# Issues creating a nested serializer in Django Rest Framework with pre existing objects

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I can't figure out what's causing this to go wrong. I am opening a new question from [this original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699778/not-null-constraint-failed-on-nested-serializer-due-to-unable-do-get-repr-for-q) since I have some newly formed issues.

I'd like to make a nested serializer accepts this JSON in a POST request and saves it:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "sender": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "anotherUser",
        "email": "anotherUser@email.com"
    },
    "recipients": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "aUser",
        "email": "user@email.com"
    }],
    "subject": "asdf",
    "body": "asdf",
    "read": false
}
```

So here is my **Serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {
                'validators': [UnicodeUsernameValidator()],
            }
        }



class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sender = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    recipients = UserSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)



    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('id', 'subject', 'body', 'read', 'sender', 'recipients')


    def create(self, validated_data):
        sender_data = validated_data.pop('sender')
        recipient_data = validated_data.pop('recipients')
        message = Message.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for user in recipient_data:
            user= User.objects.get(id=user['id'])
            message.recipients.save(user)

        for user in sender_data:
            user= User.objects.get(id=user['id'])
            message.sender.save(user)
        return message
```

And here is my **Models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    # TODO Make user idNum a UUIDField
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=75)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Message(models.Model):
    # TODO make message id a UUIDField
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='message_sender', null=True, blank=True)
    # TODO create many to one relationship between recipients and messages
    recipients = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='message_recip', null=True, blank=True)
```

With this code, I'm getting a Keyerror at /messages/ on 'sender'. And I see why I am getting this! It's because the Sender ForeignKey is not getting validated. Well okay. Maybe that's due to the read_only argument on the sender's serializer declaration (it is).

So, i took the the read_only argument off of the declaration so it looks like this now:

```
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

sender = UserSerializer()
recipients = UserSerializer(many=True)
```

This will fix the problem of the validation. However, I now see an AttributeError at /messages/ 'Nonetype' object has no attribute ' save'. Here's the traceback :

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/kevinyoung/AbstractPlayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/kevinyoung/AbstractPlayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/kevinyoung/AbstractPlayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/kevinyoung/AbstractPlayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kevinyoung/AbstractPlayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kevinyoung/AbstractPlayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/Users/kevinyoung/AbstractPlayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/Users/kevinyoung/AbstractPlayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kevinyoung/PycharmProjects/AbstractPlay/accounts/views.py" in post
  21.             serializer.save()

File "/Users/kevinyoung/AbstractPlayEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  215.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)

File "/Users/kevinyoung/PycharmProjects/AbstractPlay/accounts/serializers.py" in create
  33.             message.recipients.save(user)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /messages/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES: No cookie data
```

So I start debugging and notice that on the line

```
user= User.objects.get(id=user['id'])
```

User is set to Type "< accounts.models.DoesNotExist>"

Okay, that makes sense, the User it's getting back isn't actually a user... interesting. I took a closer look at the docs, and I think maybe its a writable serializer I want, even though I dont want to create new users when ever a message is sent, maybe I can manipulate it.

So I then try changing the line that 'gets' the user object to creating a new user object instead with the ordered dict that is stored in the user variable, like this :

```
user= User.objects.get(id=user['id'])
```

And now I get a UniqueConstraint error on the user.id

Which makes sense, I was trying to make a new User with the same unique id. My problem is, I just dont know where to go from here. I get the feeling it has to do with my **str** method on my User model? But my changes don't seem to be helping.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
    extra_kwargs = {
        'id': {
            'validators': [UnicodeUsernameValidator()],
        }
    }
```

seems weird, why id needs validation?

Second, and most importantly, you seem to want to get list of messages, but your traceback shows you are calling `create`.
You are not showing us what your `/messages` end point should look like.

My guess is that you are not `GET` -ing but `POST` ing the endpoint.

Third, `recipients = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='message_recip', null=True, blank=True)` won't give you list of recipients but just one.

Fourth `message.recipients.save(user)` doesn't make sense.
What you want is probably `message.recipients = user; user.save()`

To sum up, your code shows you are hitting errors on so many things. I suggest you to break down what you want and complete each step at once.

You could start 'getting list of messages but title only'

Comment: 1. That validation was left over from when I was matching from user name, forgot to take that out, thank you for reminding me.

2. Yes, I actually am trying to POST, not GET, I worded that poorly and I will edit the original post.

3. Do I need to make a ListField then? I was getting some other errors when I did that which i didnt quite understand.

yeah the most annoying part is I did have a basic working example where I could get message data without the list of recipients and senders... Im thinking I might have to go back to that and start from scratch after all of this suffering.

Comment: Something else to note: I took out the validation mentioned in youre first observation. I now get a failed validation on my POST method, on the condition " if serializer.is_valid(): " Which makes the response tell me "that user already exists"... which is actually what i want, i want an already existing user to be added to this object.